# Perform bulk insertion in background using asyncio

Tags: python, mongodb, python-asyncio

Hi I'm using native coroutines, asyncio motor client to access mongo db using python. My problem scenario is to call the insert function and get the future object, use this returned future object to determine to send success response say 200 or failure response say 400. Later the insertion in db should happen in background. I'm expecting it to done by event loops but I'm not able to find suitable solution for it.

```
@post(_path="/insert",_types=[TestRequest],
                    _consumes=Config.APPLICATION_JSON,
                     _produces=Config.APPLICATION_JSON)
def insertManyDocuments(self,test_req):
    try:
        collection_name='mycoll'
        documents_to_insert=[]
        for i in test_req:
            documents_to_insert.append(i.__dict__)
        future_obj=    self.xyz.insertMany(collection_name,documents_to_insert)
        status=Status()
        if future_obj is None:
            status.status_code=404
        else:
            status.status_code=202
        return status
    except Exception:
        raise Exception
#below code exists in another python file
async def insertMany(self,collection_name,documents_to_insert):
    try:
        collection=self.database[collection_name]
        self.future_obj = collection.insert_many(documents_to_insert)
        t=Timer(120.0,self.insertManyFn)
        t.start()
        return self.future_obj
    except Exception:
        raise
def insertManyFn(self):
    try:
        loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(self.future_obj)
        loop.close()
    except Exception:
        raise
```

Comment: share your attempt and their results please

Comment: Above code doesn't works as insertMany fn. is not getting called because I'm not using event loops, if I use asyncio.get_event_loop.run_until_complete(insertMany(...)) then it will wait for the insertion, which will fail the functionality which I want to achieve. Is there any other way to call async fn. from API